# Add HTML to looped items, except first item

Tags: bigcartel

Is it possible to get the `for` loop item count, and then add HTML to all items after the first?

Working code:

```
{% for page in pages.all limit:6 %}
<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

HTML would look like:

```
<li>
  List Item 1
</li>
<li>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  List Item 2
</li>
<li>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  List Item 3
</li>
```

I tried something like this, but it did not work:

```
{% for page in pages.all limit:6 %}
<li>{% if page != 1 %}<span class="spacer"></span>{% endif %}{{ page | link_to }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... `forloop.index`

```
{% for page in pages.all limit:6 %}
<li>{% if forloop.index != 1 %}<span class="spacer"></span>{% endif %}{{ page | link_to }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add boolean variable `first_item`, which is initialized to `true`, and then use

```
<li>{% if first_item %}<span class="spacer"></span>{% endif %}{{ page | link_to }}</li>
```

followed by assignment of `false` to `first_item` variable.